# SQL Query Return All Results from Table A and Only Results from Table B that are not included in Table A

Tags: sql, join, union

I am trying to query two tables and return a single result set that includes all values from table A and only values from Table B that are not included in Table A.

```
Table A        Table B
ID  Name       ID  Name
A   John       C   Drew
B   Jacob      D   Shane
C   Nancy
```

Based on the ID column, result set should be:

```
ID  Name
A   John
B   Jacob
C   Nancy
D   Shane
```

I would exclude ID C from Table B from the result set because table A has a record with an ID of C.

Does anyone know how I would begin to accomplish this?

Comment: @philipxy - I looked at the post. Union/Union All removes duplicates based on all values of a row being duplicated. In this case, only the ID is duplicated, but I want to return the result of the first Table, not the second.

Comment: Thanks. Your description of what you want is not what you want, so it shouldn't be there, and your description of your example is not a statement of what you want either, so you should say what you want. So this is not clear, which is another reason to close & downvote. If you write out clearly (many phrasings of) what you want, you can reason about, google for & ask about parts & the whole. Otherwise, you can't. Observe how the accepted answer is a combination of union (obvious faq) & finding rows in a table that don't match another table (obvious faq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as using `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select a.id, a.name
from a
union all
select b.id, b.name
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.id = b.id);
```